# ReferenceError while using HashHistory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am learning `React` and am following [this](https://online.reacttraining.com/courses/reactjsfundamentals/lectures/760339) tutorial. Here's my routes.js file:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var historyHistory = ReactRouter.hashHistory;
var IndexRoute = ReactRouter.IndexRoute;


var Main = require('../components/Main');
var Home = require('../components/Home');


var routes = (
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={Main}>
      <IndexRoute path='/home' component={Home} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
);

module.exports = routes;
```

and the installed dependencies in package.json :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.20.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.9",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.24.1",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
```

Using this code, I am getting this error:
`ReferenceError: hashHistory is not defined`

If I remove hashHistory, I get this error:
`ReferenceError: history is not defined`

I cant understand the error as, if I am not using hashHistory, what `history` is the error pointing to?

The line that's the culprit (present in `dist/index_bundle.js`, some generated code) is:

> ```
>   !history.getCurrentLocation ? process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? (0, _invariant2.default)(false, 'You have provided a history object created with history v2.x or ' + 'earlier. This version of React Router is only compatible with v3 ' + 'history objects. Please upgrade to history v3.x.') : (0, _invariant2.default)(false) : void 0;
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing ReactRouter.hashHistory as var historyHistory on line 5.

So when you render the Router component you should do history={historyHistory} or rename the variable on top to hashHistory.

Edit: The error you get when you leave out history entirely is, because history is a mandatory prop.

Comment: Thanks, I feel stupid right now :) Also, in the tutorial, it worked for the guy without including history. Is it a change from prev versions as he was using react 2.0.0 and I am using 3.0.0?

Comment: Yep, it was not required in earlier versions I think

Answer (score 0):

Simply import all required things in one line, like this:

```
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from 'react-router'
```

Then use these same name in rendering.

Comment: I'm getting this `You have provided a history object created with history v2.x or earlier. This version of React Router is only compatible with v3 history objects. Please upgrade to history v3.x.`

Comment: fixed with this `import { createHistory } from 'history'; // you need to install this package
let history = createHistory();`